# Amazon dax client not working as per TTL set on the item

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I have setup Dynamodb table and using it for caching purposes, I have dax client setup as well and writing and reading using `node.js`'s `amazon-dax-client`. DAX client is not obeying the ttl set on the item.

Here is the configuration of the table,
[image]

You can see, caching enabled and CacheTTL is set as the ttl attirbute.

Here's the code to write and read items to the cache table.

```
class DynamodbCache {
  constructor () {
    this.dax = new AmazonDaxClient({
      endpoints: process.env.DAX_CLIENT,
      region,
    })

    this.daxClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: this.dax })
    this.tableName = process.env.DAX_TABLENAME
  }

  async set(key, value, options = {}) {
    const epochSeconds = this.calculateTTL(options)
    const params = {
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Item: {
        CacheKey: key,
        CacheValue: value,
        CacheTTL: epochSeconds,
      },
    }
    await this.daxClient.put(params).promise()
  }

  async get(key) {
    const params = {
      Key: {
        CacheKey: key,
      },
      TableName: this.tableName,
    }

    const response = await this.daxClient.get(params).promise()
    const { Item = {} } = response
    return Item.CacheValue
  }

  calculateTTL(options = {}) {
    const { ttl = 300 } = options
    if (ttl <= 0) {
      return undefined
    }
    const epochSeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + ttl
    return epochSeconds
  }
}
```

The following snapshot shows that the cache is being hit even after the max-age is expired.
[image]

Comment: I think that you are confusIng the ttl on the dynamodb table and the cache ttl in dax. You can control dax configurations by going to the dax dashboard (see on the left nav when you are in the dynamodb console). What you are showing in the screenshot is the TTL on the dynamodb table which will remove the item from table but not invalidate your cache.

Comment: I don’t think that you can set the ttl in dax (not dynamodb) on a per item basis. For that you would need to use Elasticache either with memcached or redis.

Comment: Yes, whatever I am trying to accomplish is not possible with Dax. I moved to Redis.